# Does the order of type specifiers matter in C?

Tags: c, types

Is there an expected ordering when combining type specifiers in C? *e.g.* `short`, `long`, `signed`, `unsigned` If order has meaning, what is the effect when changing the order of the type modifier?

For example, sometimes I see people use `long unsigned int`, other times `unsigned long int`. Do these mean the same thing?

Comment: Integral type declaration specifiers can appear in any order but may not be duplicated or conflict with another. I would not place trust in either of these AI systems if I were you.

Comment: I am curious what was the exact question you asked the AI and what was the exact answer?  It's possible it didn't under stand the question. Textually, the are different strings. I second @paddy's comment. Never trust an AI.

Comment: Regarding downvote, I have no idea. I think fundamentally it's a reasonable question. Some people automatically downvote questions that talk about ChatGPT, which is kinda taboo on Stack Overflow. Don't worry about it. We all get downvotes sometimes. It's not important.

Comment: I have updated the question to remove the parts about asking AI, since there was no information about how the question was asked, nor how it was answered. Stating that fact added nothing extra to the underlying question, and citing conversations with AI on Stack Overflow is at best a gray area.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The C17 language standard (N2310) ([link](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2310.pdf)) specifies the allowed type specifiers:

> 6.7.2 Type specifiers
>
> 2. At least one type specifier shall be given in the declaration specifiers in each declaration, and in
>    the specifier-qualifier list in each struct declaration and type name. Each list of type specifiers shall
>    be one of the following multisets (delimited by commas, when there is more than one multiset per
>    item); the type specifiers may occur in any order, possibly intermixed with the other declaration
>    specifiers.
>
>    - **void**
>    - **char**
>    - **signed char**
>    - **unsigned char**
>    - **short**, **signed short**, **short int**, or **signed short int**
>    - **unsigned short**, or **unsigned short int**
>    - **int**, **signed**, or **signed int**
>    - **unsigned**, or **unsigned int**
>    - **long**, **signed long**, **long int**, or **signed long int**
>    - **unsigned long**, or **unsigned long int**
>    - **long long**, **signed long long**, **long long int**, or **signed long long int**
>    - **unsigned long long**, or **unsigned long long int**
>    - **float**
>    - **double**
>    - **long double**
>    - **_Bool**
>    - **float _Complex**
>    - **double _Complex**
>    - **long double _Complex**
>    - atomic type specifier
>    - struct or union specifier
>    - enum specifier
>    - typedef name

Where *type specifier* means any single word here, such as `unsigned`, `int`, `long`, *etc*. That's defined in (1) of this section, but I did not quote it here.

So, (2) explicitly states *"the type specifiers may occur in any order"*. Later in the section, we get further clarification that all multisets in a comma-separated list describes the same type:

> 5. Each of the comma-separated multisets designates the same type, except that for bit-fields, it is
>    implementation-defined whether the specifier **int** designates the same type as **signed int** or the
>    same type as **unsigned int**.

That means the ordering is not important, and therefore any ordering describes the same type.

For general readability of your code, consider using the orderings that are actually shown in the specification. They are the most common.

---

### Example

The following types are identical:

- `signed long int`
- `long signed int`
- `signed int long`
- `int signed long`
- `long int signed`
- `int long signed`

Not only that, but all the others in the list of multisets are identical to the above:

- `long`
- `signed long`
- `long signed`
- `long int`
- `int long`

Let's take a more ridiculous one. It is valid to call your type `long signed int long`, which is equivalent to `long long`. Would you want to? Hopefully not!

---

Regarding your followup comment:

> my question apply to other type of datatype too like int, float, char, double

This is entirely defined by the specification that I quoted. But let's take `float` as an example. There are two multisets where `float` appears. They are `float` and `float _Complex`. There is no such thing as `long float`, for instance. But you could have `_Complex float`.

Perhaps using `_Complex` as an example isn't great, given this:

> 3. The type specifier _Complex shall not be used if the implementation does not support complex types

Note that `char` is actually a distinct type that can be implicitly signed or unsigned depending on the compiler configuration. This is a point of difference from the other integral types that are implicitly signed.

Comment: I’m sorry but you still haven’t answer my question. I’m asking strictly about the order of combination of type modifier ie long, short, signed, unsigned. Is there a rule about that said order ie can I declare a variable with long unsigned or unsigned long with the type specifier at the end of the multiset ie long unsigned int. Does changing that order affect anything?

Comment: Did you miss the bit that says _"the type specifiers may occur in any order"_?

Comment: Yikes sorry, english is not my native. Tbh when I read that part I also realy confused.

Comment: What I got out of this is I need to try and get `long signed int long` through a code review. :)

Comment: Fair call, it was hidden away there, and sorry for being a bit curt with you! :) I didn't quote enough of the standard to really make it clear. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: To make things even more interesting, you can mix in type qualifiers where you please too. And to make it even more interesting, C allows you to use the same type qualifier as many times as you like. `const long const signed const int const long const* const const const ptr;` is perfectly valid C, 100% equivalent to `const long* const ptr;`. I would like to say "it's such a broken language that it ain't even funny", but it _is_ quite funny how broken C is :) And _of course_ this madness wasn't fixed in C99, C11, C17, C23...

Comment: I'm sure that's a crucial feature that IOCCC contestants rely on!